# Add a column from one dataframe in a list to another dataframe in another list with map2

Tags: r, list, dataframe, purrr

I have two lists with different dataframes (original data has 70 dataframes for each list, totalising 2 million rows).

```
df1 <- data.frame(colA = LETTERS[1:5], colB = seq(1,5))
df2 <- data.frame(colA = LETTERS[6:10], colB = seq(6,10))
list1 <- list(df1,df2)
df3 <- data.frame(colA = LETTERS[1:5], colB = seq(11,15))
df4 <- data.frame(colA = LETTERS[6:10], colB = seq(16,20))
list2 <- list(df3,df4)
```

I want either to create a new list (e.g., `desired_list`) or to update the existing `list1`, adding `colB` from each dataframe of `list2` (`df3` and `df4`) naming the new column accordingly and re-naming the old ones.
`list1` and `list2` have the same number of dataframes, each of them has the same number of rows (`df1` has the same number of rows of `df3`, `df2` of `df4`, and so on). The desired output should looks like this.

```
desired_df1 <- data.frame(colA = LETTERS[1:5], colB_1 = seq(1,5), colB_2 = seq(11,15))
desired_df2 <- data.frame(colA = LETTERS[6:10], colB_1 = seq(6,10), colB_2 = seq(16,20))
desired_list <- list(desired_df1,desired_df2)
```

I think I can do this with `purrr::map2` but I´am not very familiar with lists and I am having difficulties with `map2` formatting and indexing. So far I tried:

```
desired_list <- lapply(list1, 
                       function(df) {purrr::map2(.x = list1, .y = list2, .f = list1$colB_2 <- list2$colB)})
```

But I get:

```
Error in `as_mapper()`:
! Can't convert `.f`, NULL, to a function.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain old `Map` for this:

```r
Map(function(a, b) { a$colB_2 <- b$colB; a }, list1, list2)
#> [[1]]
#>   colA colB colB_2
#> 1    A    1     11
#> 2    B    2     12
#> 3    C    3     13
#> 4    D    4     14
#> 5    E    5     15
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   colA colB colB_2
#> 1    F    6     16
#> 2    G    7     17
#> 3    H    8     18
#> 4    I    9     19
#> 5    J   10     20
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried Map but in a for loop and it was a mess. That did exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following:

```r
map2(list1, list2,
     ~data.frame(colA = .x$colA,
                 colB_1 = .x$colB,
                 colB_2 = .y$colB))

##> [[1]]
##>   colA colB_1 colB_2
##> 1    A      1     11
##> 2    B      2     12
##> 3    C      3     13
##> 4    D      4     14
##> 5    E      5     15
##> 
##> [[2]]
##>   colA colB_1 colB_2
##> 1    F      6     16
##> 2    G      7     17
##> 3    H      8     18
##> 4    I      9     19
##> 5    J     10     20
```

Comment: Thanks Stefano, this works and helped me understanding better map2 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Or may also extract `colB` from `list2` and `transform` the `list1`

```
 Map(transform, list1, colB_2 = lapply(list2, `[[`, "colB"))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
  colA colB colB_2
1    A    1     11
2    B    2     12
3    C    3     13
4    D    4     14
5    E    5     15

[[2]]
  colA colB colB_2
1    F    6     16
2    G    7     17
3    H    8     18
4    I    9     19
5    J   10     20
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what exactly does `[[` ? I have seen it before but never used it.

Comment: @LisaTedeschi It is used to extract the column as a vector